# how can I limit a text box to display 2 digit after decimal point?

Tags: c#

how can I limit a text box to display 2 digit after decimal point ?

123.22 - true

1000000.123 - false

0.002 - false

3.32 - true

12a.34 - false

thank's in advance

Comment: are you outputting values to the TextBox or having the user enter data?

Comment: what tool are you using to build your form?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a NumericUpDown control and set the DecimalPlaces property to 2. This will allow the user to enter more than two decimal places, but when they tab out of it, it'll round their input either up or down.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please explain more. You want to create textbox with mask or to check existing value in textbox. If you want to create mask you can use MaskedTextBox control.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a webform you can add a regular expression check to the on Validate event to check to see if the data is in the right format, something like

```
^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$
```

should do the trick.

Of course you can do a similar thing on webforms using a regular expression validator.